# Using node.js for my server, need to setup user accounts, which database program should I use?

Tags: database, node.js, user-accounts

I'm pretty new to the whole node.js thing (as well as servers, javascript and the internet in general).  I'm setting up a node.js server and I want to be able to create user accounts.

Assumption 1: This requires using a database of some sort.

At first I was going to go with mySQL because it's the first DBMS I could think of and it's open source and there's a node.js module for it.  But reading through stack overflow and other sites, everyone is talking about using mongoose, redis and other things.

What should I use?  Why should I use it?  How far away from making sense am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is a fast key-value store which is great for something like session. I see a lot of MongoDB with Mongoose in the community but I am more of a CouchDB person myself.

If you like learning new stuff you can try a few of them and see which one you like. If you have a deadline and you know MySql I would just stick with that for now.

Comment: I'm pretty much a lost puppy with respect to this stuff (no previous experience).  All I need is secure and usable - I'm guessing all of the above can be used for user accounts in some manner?

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is a good choice. I'm a huge fan of [Redis](http://redis.io) myself (even for a small, everyday DB).

If you don't need an ORM type modeling for your data, I suggest [MongoJS](https://github.com/gett/mongojs) or [Mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin). They both make it really easy to interface with MongoDB with very little code.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a project that you are just building on your local machine for learning, then [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) with [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) and [mongoose-auth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/mongoose-auth) can give you a pretty quick start.

If you are planning to deploy this to production somewhere you should find out what your hosting provider offers. If you have not picked a hosting provider checkout [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/). They offer [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) and they make it really easy to deploy your app without having to worry about server setup and config, etc.

Comment: Hmm, right now we're planning on setting up on AWS which already has mySQL.  But I'll definitely check out Heroku, thank you!